# How to use nested loop in this example?

Tags: php, loops, logic

Consider the following `$data` array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => 20
            [name] => Name 1
            [month] => 4
            [cost] => 100
            ..
            ..
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => 30
            [name] => Name 2
            [month] => 3
            [cost] => 120
            ..
            ..
        ) 

    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => 30
            [name] => Name 2
            [month] => 6
            [cost] => 180
            ..
            ..
        )    

    ..
    ..
)
```

Each array can have unknown number of codes. Each code has a different month ID. I want to sort and display the data so that there is just one row for the each code, and then in that row, display the value of the `[cost]` in the column number equal to the month. For example:

```
Column      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10     11    12
Name 1                       100
Name 2                  120               180
```

**Here's what I'm trying:**

In order to find out how many rows should be printed, I fetch the unique code values:

```
$codes = array();                   
foreach( $data as $row ){ 
    if ( in_array($row['code'], $codes) ) {
        continue;
    }
    $codes[] = $row['code'];
}
```

Next, I use a loop to print the rows:

```
foreach( $codes as $code ){

    //print 12 columns for each othe row
    for ($i = 1; $<=12; $i++) {

        //display column value if the code is same as the row
        //and the month value is same as $i
        //here's the problem
        if (( $data['code'] == $code ) &&( $data['month'] == $i )) {
            echo $data['cost'];
        }

    }
}
```

**Problem/Question:**
Do I need to put another loop inside the for loop to check if the `$data['code'] == $code` ? Or how can I do that?

Comment: Can you post an example of the desired output array ?

Comment: @Reqven I just posted the desired output example above. Basically I want to run a loop for each month (1-12) for each code, and if the array has data for that code and month then just print it in a table as I wrote in question.

Comment: So does your current code output correct data?

Comment: @u_mulder no, that's why i posted the question. That if condition doesnt match, I'm not sure if I need another loop inside the for loop above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use one loop to re-index the array:

```
$list = $codes = [];
for ($array as $item){
    $list[$item['code']][$item['month']] = $item;
    $codes[$item['code']] = $item['name'];
}
```

then use two loops to print:

```
for ($codes as $code => $codeName){
    echo '<tr><th>', $codeName, '</th>';
    for (range(1, 12) as $month){
        echo '<td>', ($list[$code][$month]['cost'] ?? ''), '</td>;
    }
    echo '</tr>', "\n";
}
```

I really do not like the idea of if()s inside the loops.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think `echo '<td>', ($item[$code][..` should be `$list[..`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you preprocess your data to a structured array first and then you print it, for example, indexed by code with a structure like:

```
[
  ['the code'] => [
     'name' => '',
     'months' => [ 
        '6' => // cost
     ]
  ]
]
```

You can do it like this:

```
$items = [
    [
        'code' => 20,
        'name' => 'Name 1',
        'month' => 4,
        'cost' => 100,
    ],
    [
        'code' => 30,
        'name' => 'Name 2',
        'month' => 3,
        'cost' => 120,
    ],
    [
        'code' => 30,
        'name' => 'Name 2',
        'month' => 6,
        'cost' => 180,
    ],
];

$sortedItems = [];
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (!isset($sortedItems[$item['code']])) {
        $sortedItems[$item['code']] = [
            'name' => $item['name'],
            'months' => [],
        ];
    }

    $sortedItems[$item['code']]['months'][$item['month']] = $item['cost'];
}
```

You can the print it using a function similar to this:

```
function printItemsOf(array $list) {
    echo '<table>';

    // print header
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>Column</td>';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        echo '<td>' . $i . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    // print items
    foreach ($list as $code => $item) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $item['name'] . '</td>';

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
            if (!isset($item['months'][$i])) {
                echo '<td></td>';
            } else {
                echo '<td>' . $item['months'][$i] . '</td>';
            }
        }

        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}
```

Which outputs:

```html
<table border="1"><tr><td>Column</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr><tr><td>Name 1</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>100</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>Name 2</td><td></td><td></td><td>120</td><td></td><td></td><td>180</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
```